# spyder plotly : issue with plotting barplots

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, spyder, data-analysis

[please notice barplot('Age',False) runs without any error but fails to plot graph in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS81V.png)I'm using spyder to analyse employee attrition of ibm hr employee dataset from kaggle. For plotting graphs I'm using plotly library but I can't plot barplots using this library whereas I can successfully plot scatter plots and pie charts.
Attaching sample code of my work
spyder was successful to print `plot_distribution('Age', False)` this graph in chrome but can't plot `barplot('Age', False)`

```
def barplot(var_select, x_no_numeric) :
tmp1 = data[(data['Attrition'] != 0)]
tmp2 = data[(data['Attrition'] == 0)]
tmp3 = pd.DataFrame(pd.crosstab(data[var_select], data['Attrition']), )
tmp3['Attr%'] = tmp3[1] / (tmp3[1] + tmp3[0]) * 100
if x_no_numeric == True:
    tmp3 = tmp3.sort_values(1, ascending=False)
    color = ['skyblue', 'gold']
    trace1 = go.Bar(
            x = tmp1[var_select].value_counts().keys().tolist(),
            y = tmp2[var_select].value_counts().values.tolist(),
            name = 'yes_attrition', opacity = 0.8,
            marker = dict(color = 'gold', line=dict(color='#000000',width=1)))
    trace2 = go.Bar(
            x = tmp1[var_select].value_counts().keys().tolist(),
            y = tmp2[var_select].value_counts().values.tolist(),
            name = 'no_attrition', opacity = 0.8,
            marker = dict(color='skyblue', line=dict(color='#000000',width=1)))
    trace3 = go.Scatter(
            x = tmp3.index,
            y = tmp3['Attr%'],
            yaxis = 'y2',
            name = '%Attrition', opacity= 0.5,
            marker= dict(color='black',line=dict(color='#000000',width=0.5)))
    layout = dict(title= str(var_select),
            xaxis = dict(),
            yaxis = dict(title='count'),
            yaxis2 = dict(range= [-0,75],
                          overlaying = 'y',
                          anchor = 'x',
                          side = 'right',
                          Zeroline = False,
                          showgrid = False,
                          title = '%Attrition'))
    fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2, trace3], layout= layout)
    py.plot(fig)

plot_distribution('Age', False)
barplot('Age', False)
```

Comment: and what would be the error? (please try to include it everytime you ask for help)

Comment: @Alexis ty for your reply, when i run plot_distribution('Age',False) spyder plots the corresponding graph in chrome but when i run barplot('Age', False) this line simply passes in console without any error but i don't get any graphs in chrome..tried running the same code both in spyder and jupyter notebook..still no luck..i think i have done some syntax error which i can't find

Comment: can you fix the indentation please, because from what i see you have a `if x_no_numeric == True:` that won't allow you to plot anything if you pass False in arguments